# Visual Studio 2013: auto-refresh solution explorer in "show all files" mode

Tags: visual-studio-2013, automation, solution-explorer

Is there any way or some unobvious workaround to make the Solution Explorer refresh automatically (in *Show All Files* mode) when there are changes to the project directory tree? Currently if I rebuild a project with different output settings (which would add some files and remove some others), no changes would get reflected in Solution Explorer until I **manually** click *refresh* button. Doesn't seem too convenient for a tool aimed at programming, i.e. automating repetitive tasks...

---

**Update**

A picture is worth a thousand words:

My relevant options @ *Tools > Options > Environment > Documents*:

---

[image: options]

---

1. Let's assume that *Release* directory is empty and *Show All Files* mode enabled

[image: before build]

2. Now, I build my Release config... Build succeeds, but no changes are visible in Solution Explorer:

[image]

3. Only after I hit *refresh* button manually can I see the results of build process:

[image]

So I'm basically asking if there are ways to make Solution Explorer update automatically when changes occur, not to make externally modified files auto-reload in VS editors.

Comment: This is not the proper place to talk to Microsoft.  Post feature requests at visualstudio.uservoice.com.  Don't hold your breath for this one.

Comment: First I wanted to make sure I'm not overlooking some way to achieve the desired behavior... I would accept a direct statement that it's not possible in VS2013 as an answer, thank you for stating that implicitly, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sunny Moon - There is no option right now to automatically refresh the project tree if changes are introduced. You have to manually select the Refresh button in the command bar of Solution Explorer. I'm going to track this feedback along with other areas I've been collecting for Solution Explorer so thanks for sharing your frustration here.

Thanks!
Cathy
Visual Studio IDE Team

Comment: Is this still the case for 2015?

Comment: Yep, it totally is. But our frustration is being thanked, at least.

Comment: ... And in Visual Studio 2017 they finally implemented it! Now I'm thanking you, VS IDE team :)

Answer (score 1):

Just set check the “Auto-load changes, if saved” check box on VS2013 Option menu >> Environment menu.

Comment: Sorry, no, this setting enables automatic reloading of files opened in VS editor when they are modified externally. It doesn't make Solution Explorer update when project folder contents change (at least for me). I've added some pictures to clarify my question. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

That was impossible in VS 2013 and 2015, but with 2017 Microsoft did the right thing and revamped the Solution Explorer a bit - now there is clear and logical separation between solution (virtual) and folder (physical) views, and changes to the filesystem are now tracked and displayed automatically.